# DHL shipping module not working

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-community, magento-1.9

I have Magento 1.7.0.2

The DHL shipping module does not work. I enable it in the Admin and all it does is display the error message specified in the config when trying to use it on the frontend.

I read somewhere else that there was a bug with this module in 1.7.0.2 where it was sending empty headers and that the only fix was to upgrade to 1.9. There was mention that there was an update to the Varien library that would fix the issue.

Well, I can't upgrade to 1.9 so I'm wondering if there's any other way to fix the issue?

---

Here is the DHL error log:

```
2014-06-15T01:34:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Error parsing body - doesn't seem to be a chunked message
    [1] => The response is in wrong format.
    [__pid] => 27568
)
```